# D3 How to filter data from multiple datasets

Tags: d3.js

I am using data from a CSV that looks like this

```
,,Name,First names,s,r,Nat,born,starting point,starting date,arrival date,days,km,Assist,Support,Style,note,arrival date 2
1,1,KAGGE,Erling,,,Nor,1/15/1963,Berkner Island,11/18/1992,1/7/1993,50,appr. 1300,n,n,solo,first solo unassisted,
2,2,ARNESEN,Liv,f,,Nor,6/1/1953,Hercules Inlet,11/4/1994,12/24/1994,50,1130,n,n,solo,first woman unassisted,
```

I'm using this CSV to create a dropdown menu of'starting point' and this filters all 'Name' associated with that 'starting point'

I want to create an additional dataset that will allow me to add some extra details to each 'starting point' such as 'x', like this: (I want to use this to create some svg lines unique to each 'starting point')

```
var newdata = [
 {'starting point': 'Berkner Island', 'x': '1'}, 
 {'starting point': 'Hercules Inlet', 'x': '2'},
 {'starting point': 'Ronne Ice Shelf','x': '3'}
];
```

I am filtering the data like this

```
var filter = data.filter(function(d) {
 return ("Berkner Island" == d['starting point'])
});

updateCSV(filter);    // CSV data function
updateNewdata(filter);   // Newdata function
```

When it loads, only the CSV data is filtered. The second dataset 'newdata' loads all entries with no filter applied to it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/TgZxbaPdyERWeaG5i3HX?p=info

My question is, is it possible to use a second dataset, and filter two different datasets by a shared value?

**UPDATE**

I managed to work it out, and yes it is possible. I wasn't understanding that the callback in the function could have a unique name, and not just 'data'. Once I did this and created two distinct filters for each of my datasets, it worked.

```
function updateCSV(CSVdata) {
    ...
    .data(CSVdata)
};

function updateNewdata(newdata) {
    ...
    .data(newdata)
};


// FILTER
var filtera = CSVdata.filter(function(d) {
   return ("Berkner Island" == d['starting point'])
});

var filterb = newdata.filter(function(d) {
   return ("Berkner Island" == d['starting point'])
});

updateCSV(filtera);
updateNewdata(filterb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is here. You're not actually using the data you pass in.

```
// should this say 'newdata' not 'data'?
function updateNewdata(data) {
  var position = canvas
   .selectAll(".position")
   .data(newdata)
```

Comment: I'm not sure. If I change that, a group named '.position' is created for every 'Name' from my CSV data. I only want to load this group for each 'starting point' in 'newdata'

Comment: Are you passing the correct data into `updateNewData`? Right now, you pass in `updateNewData(filter)`. Should it be `updateNewData(newdata)`?

Comment: Yes I think so, my data from newdata is loading fine, its just in the wrong place or not filtering properly. Removing the filter function without doing something else in its place isn't going to do anything.